# MySQL Trigger, vague syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Using MySQL 5.5, the following trigger is getting rejected with an error:

```
create trigger nodups
before insert on `category-category`
for each row
begin
    if(catid >= relatedid) then
        signal 'catid must be less than relatedid';
    end if
end;
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>       that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>       near '-category for each row begin if(catid >= relatedid) then signal 'catid
>       must be l' at line 1

**What is wrong with the syntax for this trigger?**

For what it's worth, I'm just trying to prevent inserts with `catid >= relatedid`.  I am open to other methods of achieving this goal.

---

**Edit:**
The query above is being entered on a single line, semi-colons and all.

I tried it again using a delimiter.  Here is the result:

```
mysql> delimiter ###
mysql> create trigger nodups
    -> before insert on `category-category`
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> if(catid >= relatedid) then   
    -> signal 'catid must be less than relatedid';
    -> end if
    -> end;
    -> ###
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''catid must be less than relatedid';
end if
end' at line 6
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` is a special character. You need to escape a table containg special characters with backticks

```
delimiter |
create trigger nodups
before insert on `category-category`
for each row
begin
    if(catid >= relatedid) then
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'catid must be less than relatedid';
    end if;
end;
|
delimiter
```

You also need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the DB thinks your trigger definition ends at the first `;` which would be incomplete.

Comment: Actually, the error is slightly different:  `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end if end' at line 1`

Comment: I added an edit to the question...the trigger is being entered in a single line at the MySQL terminal prompt

Comment: Got it...was also missing the semi-colon after `end if`.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that `category-category` is not a valid identifier.  Enclose it in backquotes:

```
create trigger nodups
before insert on `category-category`
. . .
```